# If $\mathfrak{p}\subset R$ is a minimal prime divisor of $\mathrm{Ann}_R(M)$, then $\mathrm{Ann}_R(M/\mathfrak{p}M)=\mathfrak{p}$

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra

$\DeclareMathOperator\Ann{Ann}$Let $R=\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. I am looking for a reference of the following statement.

> $(*)$ Let $M$ be an $R$-module, and let $\mathfrak{p}$ is a minimal prime divisor of $\Ann_R(M)$. Then $\Ann_R(M/\mathfrak{p}M)=\mathfrak{p}$.

Here $\mathfrak{p}$ being a minimal prime divisor means that when we take a primary decomposition $\Ann_R(M)=\bigcap_{i=1}^m\mathfrak{q_i}$, $\mathfrak{p}$ is a minimal prime appearing in the set $\{\sqrt{\mathfrak{q}_i}\}$.

Of course the point of $(*)$ is that no finiteness assumption is made on $M$. I have a proof for $(*)$, but it is quite long and technical, so I would prefer to refer to a standard reference. I have looked in some books but cannot find this statement. Does someone know of a reference?